# Is $x\int_{0}^{x}f(t) dt = \int_{0}^{x}x f(t) dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration

In a book an equation states,

$$e^{xA}\int_{0}^{x} e^{-tA} Q(t) dt = \int_{0}^{x} e^{(x-t)A} Q(t) dt$$

Can a variable with 'x' be shifting inside the integral? Even though the integrand is a function of 't', isn't 'x' still is a variable?

Comment: Please format your latex code. You can do so by surrounding the code with dollar signs \$

Comment: Done. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Since the integrand is a function of $t$, $e^{xA}$ is treated as a constant, isn't it? like how $2\int$=$\int 2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as integration w.r.t $t$ is concerned we can treat $x$ as a constant. So it is legitimate to take any function of $x$ inside the integral.